# Populate rows on a table based on a value from table footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="ccTransactions" class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Transaction</td>
         <td>In</td>
         <td>Out</td>
         <td>Balance</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>Card Sale</td>
         <td>+£16.98</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>Card Sale</td>
         <td>+£14.10</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>Total: </td>
         <td>Total: </td>
         <td>Final: £1334.05</td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

The table is being create when I supply a start and end date. It can only get the final balance for the end date selected. My question is, is there a way to populate the `balance` rows based on the final `balance` value that I have? Also, how can I add up the total amount from the `in` and `out` columns and display them in the table footer?

**Update:**

I've used this code to add up the `out` values. It worked on a different table where there where no empty rows, but doesn't work on this one.

```
  var currencySymbol = '-£'
  var total = 0.0;
  $('table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(currencySymbol, ''));
  });
  var $newTR = $("<tr><td colSpan='3'></td><td>Total: £"+total.toFixed(2)+"</td><td></td></tr>");
```

Comment: You've forgotten to add the relevant JavaScript to your post.

Comment: @Teemu I forgot to specify that the table is being created in the backend using PHP

Comment: But ofcourse you've tried something to solve the problem, that's what we want to see.

Comment: I think first you should query the table headers and get the index of the `in` column header, after that you have an index to use when querying the rest of the rows data cells. 

after querying all the relevant `data-cells[index of IN header]` sum the `innerHTML` of  those values (but be sure to use string.replace to get rid of the +£ signs before summing.)

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I've added an update with what I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const priceToNumber = number => +number.replace(/(^[-+£]*)([0-9]*[?.][0-9]{0,2})/g, '$2')

const getHeaderIndex = column => {
 let i
  $('#headers td').each((index, h) => {
   if($(h).data('column') === column) {
     i = index
    }
  })
  return i
}

const filterDatumByIndex = (data, index) => {
 let arr = []
 data.each(dataArray => {
   [...data[dataArray]].forEach((child, i) => {
     if(i === index) {
       arr.push(child)
      }
    })
  })
  
  return arr
}

let dataSets = $('#data > tr').map((i, { children }) => children)

const getInBalance = () => {
 let ins = filterDatumByIndex(dataSets, getHeaderIndex('IN'))
  return ins.reduce((prev, {innerHTML}) => prev + priceToNumber(innerHTML), 0)
}

const getOutBalance = () => {
 let ins = filterDatumByIndex(dataSets, getHeaderIndex('OUT'))
  return ins.reduce((prev, {innerHTML}) => prev + priceToNumber(innerHTML), 0)
}

const getCurrentBalance = () => (getInBalance() - getOutBalance())

console.log(getInBalance())
console.log(getOutBalance())
console.log(getCurrentBalance()) //populate total with this method
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ccTransactions" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr id="headers">
      <td>Timestamp</td>
      <td>Transaction</td>
      <td data-column="IN">In</td>
      <td data-column="OUT">Out</td>
      <td>Balance</td>
    </tr>
   <tbody id="data">
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>Card Sale</td>
         <td>+£16.98</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>06/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>Card Sale</td>
         <td>+£14.10</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05/02/2018</td>
         <td>cash fee</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>-£0.50</td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>Total: </td>
         <td>Total: </td>
         <td>Final: £1334.05</td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works for the In and Out columns, but I probably needed to explain more clearly what I want to do with the Balance column. For the Balance column I have a Final balance which represents the persons current balance. From the final balance I want to workout how to populate the rows: subtract from the the balance when its Out and add when its In. It's essentially populating the balance history backwards. Can you give me an idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: No problem, I'm not too sure of your requirement but i've tried to name and write my methods to be as readable as possible, maybe take a look into the JS and see what you can take from that :-)